# Dollar variable ($) instead of jQuery within jQuery(window).load()

Tags: jquery

The Codex [[1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)] describes how to handle jQuery code that use the `$` variable. I would like to apply the described wrapper technique to the following example:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    if(jQuery('#div1').length) {
        /* do stuff */
    }
});
```

In the Codex wrapper example the `ready()` function uses the `$` parameter. As I understand it `$` should then be accepted within the callback function instead of `jQuery`. I tried doing the same with my example:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {

    if($('#div1').length) {
        /* do stuff */
    }
});
```

Using the above, Firebug's console reports `TypeError: e is not a function`.

The Codex example works without errors but I'd like it to work with `jQuery(window).load()` in order to have code run after all images have fully loaded. Can it be done?

Comment: I have answered this, because there is one distinctively best-practice answer, IMHO anyway. That being done, this is pretty much a JS/jQuery question that *accidentally* happens to have arisen in a WP environment. The core nature of the question is *off-topic* on this stack, though. Should be closed, I suppose.

Comment: I feel grateful for you quick answer. I was in doubt where to post the question as I also thought it a jQuery question. In the end I decided to post it here because it was in WP I encountered the problem due to how it handles the `$` variable.

Comment: As an aside, WP does not "handle the `$` variable" in a WP-specific way, it simply invokes the [`jQuery.noConflict();` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), right after jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), a self-executing anonymous function, to wrap your JS. Pass it the `jQuery` object and `$` as an argument:

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        if($('#div1').length) {
            /* do stuff */
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```